# Date Difference where date is in dd-mm-yyyy in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do I get number of days from difference between 2 dates where dates are in "02-01-2015" format in python Data Frame.

Comment: Your question is similar to this one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/43379531/11554324

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are strings in the form of `dd-mm-YYYY` in a pandas dataframe you could convert them to `datetime` objects and then just subtract them by specifying that you want the difference in days:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['22-05-2019', '23-05-2019', '24-05-2019']
})

# Convert to datetime objects
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%m-%Y"))

# Extract and subtract dates
d1 = df.loc[0, 'date']
d2 = df.loc[2, 'date']

diff = (d2 - d1).days
```

Comment: Given the "pandas" and "dataframe" tags, this answer might be improved by at least touching on those aspects of the question (even if it's to say "There's no builtin pandas/dataframe functionality to do X, so just use normal python to <...>")